# Are there data sets for the topology of financial assets?

Tags: data

There have been a number of articles talking about financial topology and understanding cascading failures and risk. A while back there was another article about how a small number of companies form the core of the modern financial system.

I'm wondering where we can get data of ownership of financial assets and how we can approach forming a high level topology of the economic system and then continue to granulize that.

Comment: Not a bad idea.